# Pandas: optimizing some python code by getting rid of DataFrame.apply()

Tags: python, optimization, pandas

the following code is produced using python 2.7 and pandas 0.9.1.

I have a dataframe with two columns 'minor' and 'major'. I calculate the "critical" value by taking the max absolute value of both, and build a new column called 'critic':

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(
...:     {'minor':[-6, -2.3, 19.2], 'major':[2, 3, 7.4]},
...:     index=[10,20,30])
>>> print df
    major  minor
10    2.0   -6.0
20    3.0   -2.3
30    7.4   19.2
>>> df['critic'] = df[['minor', 'major']].abs().max(axis=1)
>>> print df
    major  minor  critic
10    2.0   -6.0     6.0
20    3.0   -2.3     3.0
30    7.4   19.2    19.2
```

My issue is to build a new column, let say, 'critic_vector' showing the column's name who gave this value. Until now, I was using DataFrame.apply() this way:

```
>>> def get_col_name(row, df, headers):
        tmp = (abs(df[headers].ix[row.name]) == row['critic'])
        retval = tmp.index[tmp.argmax()]
        return retval
>>> df['critic_vector'] = df.apply(get_col_name,
                                     axis=1,
                                     args=(df ,['minor', 'major']))
>>>print df
    major  minor  critic critic_vector
10    2.0   -6.0     6.0       minor
20    3.0   -2.3     3.0       major
30    7.4   19.2    19.2       minor
```

It works correctly; however, working with big amount of data, the df.apply() function is my first bottleneck. Is there a way to do it in a straight way, without using df.apply() ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Random thoughts: to get the indices, you can use `.idxmax` instead of `max`, namely

```
>>> w = df[['minor','major']].abs().idxmax(axis=1)
>>> w
10    minor
20    major
30    minor
dtype: object
```

and then you could use `lookup` (there's probably something simpler, but I'm missing it right now):

```
>>> df.lookup(df.index, w)
array([ -6. ,   3. ,  19.2])
```

IOW:

```
>>> df['critic_vector'] = df[['minor','major']].abs().idxmax(axis=1)
>>> df['critic'] = abs(df.lookup(df.index, df.critic_vector))
>>> df
    major  minor critic_vector  critic
10    2.0   -6.0         minor     6.0
20    3.0   -2.3         major     3.0
30    7.4   19.2         minor    19.2
```

I'm not super-happy with the `lookup` line -- you could replace it with your original `max` call, of course -- but I think the `idxmax` approach isn't a bad one.

Comment: Cool! I adopt the "lookup" method:


In [8]: %timeit df['r'] = df[['minor', 'major']].abs().max(axis=1)
1000 loops, best of 3: 405 us per loop


In [9]: %timeit df['critic'] = abs(df.lookup(df.index, df.critic_vector))
10000 loops, best of 3: 118 us per loop