# DataFrame.lookup for a value in multi-index DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I'm struggling to replicate [this
solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16775214/2069099) for a multiindex columns
DataFrame.

Given this df:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import numpy as np
>>> 
>>> # given dataframe
>>> arrays = [np.array(['REF',  'A1', 'A1', 'A2', 'A2']),
>>>           np.array(['absmax', 'min', 'max', 'min', 'max'])]
>>> values = np.array([[-0.1, -0.11, 0.8, -0.7, 0.8],
>>>           [0.05, -0.2, 0.01, -0.23, 0.07],
>>>           [-0.07, -0.15, 0.23, -0.09, 0.01]])
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(values, columns=arrays).sort_index(axis=1)
>>> print(df)

     A1          A2          REF
    max   min   max   min absmax
0  0.80 -0.11  0.80 -0.70  -0.10
1  0.01 -0.20  0.07 -0.23   0.05
2  0.23 -0.15  0.01 -0.09  -0.07
```

I need to create for all columns `Ai` a sub-column `absmax` that would duplicate
`('Ai', 'min')` or `('Ai', 'max')` depending on the sign of `('REF', 'absmax')`.
Provided the previous DataFrame, I would expect:

```
      A1                 A2                REF
  absmax   max   min absmax   max   min absmax
0  -0.11  0.80 -0.11  -0.70  0.80 -0.70  -0.10
1   0.01  0.01 -0.20   0.07  0.07 -0.23   0.05
2  -0.15  0.23 -0.15  -0.09  0.01 -0.09  -0.07
```

To achieve this, I first create a `vec` column retrieving the relevant
sub-column name:

```
>>> # retrieve value to read based on REF/absmax sign
>>> df[('REF', 'vec')] = np.where(df['REF', 'absmax']<0, 'min', 'max')
>>> print(df.sort_index(axis=1))
     A1          A2          REF     
    max   min   max   min absmax  vec
0  0.80 -0.11  0.80 -0.70  -0.10  min
1  0.01 -0.20  0.07 -0.23   0.05  max
2  0.23 -0.15  0.01 -0.09  -0.07  min
```

And trying to assign the relevant value for `'A1'` (knowing I can have a bunch of `'Ai'` columns):

```
>>> # assign value
>>> df[('A1', 'absmax')] = df.lookup(df.index, df[('A1', df[('REF', 'vec')])])
>>> df.sort_index(axis=1, inplace=True)
>>> print(df)
---------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
[...]
TypeError: '('A1', 0    min
1    max
2    min
Name: (REF, vec), dtype: object)' is an invalid key
```

Which makes sense. Any idea how to solve this?

PS:

```
>>> print('pandas %s' % pd.__version__)
>>> print('numpy %s' % np.__version__)
pandas 0.20.3
numpy 1.13.1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**One way to do it**

```
ref = df[('REF', 'absmax')]

vec = np.array(['min', 'max'])[ref.ge(0).astype(int)]

lu = lambda d, vec: d.assign(absmax=d.lookup(d.index, vec))
df.filter(like='A').stack(0).groupby(level=1).apply(lu, vec=vec) \
  .unstack().swaplevel(0, 1, 1).sort_index(1).join(ref)

      A1                 A2                REF
  absmax   max   min absmax   max   min absmax
0  -0.11  0.80 -0.11  -0.70  0.80 -0.70  -0.10
1   0.01  0.01 -0.20   0.07  0.07 -0.23   0.05
2  -0.15  0.23 -0.15  -0.09  0.01 -0.09  -0.07
```

---

I could be more explicit by using `drop` instead of `filter`

```
ref = df[('REF', 'absmax')]

vec = np.array(['min', 'max'])[ref.ge(0).astype(int)]

lu = lambda d, vec: d.assign(absmax=d.lookup(d.index, vec))
df.drop(('REF', 'absmax'), 1).stack(0).groupby(level=1).apply(lu, vec=vec) \
  .unstack().swaplevel(0, 1, 1).sort_index(1).join(ref)
```